# Django ModelForm: How to perform an expensive field validation only rarely?

Tags: django, validation, django-models, django-forms

I have a model with about a dozen fields.
Its instances are created via a form with also about a dozen fields.
One of the fields is a URL for which I need to check actual accessibility.
That check requires a login and takes considerable time (about 4 seconds),
so I want to perform it as rarely as possible -- but also 
as early as a user would expect, namely, right after the URL was entered.

In short, **I would like to validate the URL upon form validation,
except when I have validated the same URL just before** (in the 
previous request).

I wonder where to put this logic.
My code uses a [`vanilla.CreationView`](http://django-vanilla-views.org/api/model-views#createview) class-based view.

```
from django.db import models
import vanilla

class MyModel(models.model):
    url = models.URLField()  # a very remote URL
    # and many others

class CreateView(vanilla.CreateView):
    model = MyModel
    template_name = "create.html"
```

I first tried to have the check directly in the model,
using [`has_changed()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/api/#checking-which-form-data-has-changed) somehow.

It took me a depressingly long time to recognize that this
cannot work (I am still new to Django):
The form cannot know what was submitted with the
*previous* POST request, because no suitable state
is available:

- The model instance does not exist yet (this is the create view!).
- The model will not help even in the `UpdateView`, 
  because the user may change the value several times 
  between two `save()` calls while the form does not 
  validate.

There appear to be two possibilities:

- Store persistent state in a separate `ValidationStatus` model.
  This sounds cumbersome and like an awful overkill.
- Have the browser send back the previous value by means
  of a hidden field.
  Sounds a lot more sensible to me.

**Two questions:**

- Are the above considerations correct?
- What is the code-minimal way to add such a hidden field
  to the actual form and manage the validation workflow?
  I would like to maintain the lovely automated support provided
  by Django and vanilla views as much as possible.

Comment: I would store a dictionary of valid urls on the session.

Comment: Another option would be to store it in a cache using the standard Django caching API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Caching!

koniiiik's comment is right on: This is a perfect use case for [caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/cache/), because in my case the accessibility of that URL 
is a global property; 
it does not depend on the user, is hence not session-dependent,
and has nothing to do with that particular form or with the model instance.

I have now implemented a simple [validator function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/validators/) attached to the 
`url` model field that goes like this:

```
    def validate_url_accessibility(url):
        cache_key = "%s is accessible" % url
        if django.core.cache.cache.get(cache_key):
            return  # alright: access has been validated before
        if not accessible(url):
            raise ValidationException("...")
        django.core.cache.cache.set(cache_key, True)
```

Works like a charm.